# Java android and json - variable confusion

Tags: java, android, json

I have an android app that is retrieving data from a mysql db via php.
It works fine, but i have a (simple) variable problem.

I want to create a variable inside MainActivity class.
Then inside MainActiviy class i have onCreate method - and inside that I have some json stuff that retrieves my data from mysql.

I now want to assign some mysql value to the variable i created in MainActivity class (it is assigned inside onResponse method from the json stuff), and then I simply want to use that variable and write it out on a textview, and I will do that in the bottom of the onCreate method.

But for some reason, it "forgets" the value I assigned to the variable, when I have to use it outside the onResponse method.
(if i set the textview text inside the onResponse method, it works fine).

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // I create the variable here
    String someString;

    TextView text;

    RequestQueue reqq;
    String showUrl = "http://www.someurl.com/get_data.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textid);

        reqq = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        JsonObjectRequest jsonob = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                showUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray dataAr = response.getJSONArray("json_data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataAr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject dat = dataAr.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Here I want to assign some data from my mysql db to the variable
                        someString = dat.getString("aar");

                        // If I set the the textview to display value of someString HERE, it works!
                        // text.setText(someString);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println(error.getMessage());
            }
        });

        reqq.add(jsonob);

        // HERE i want to display the value of the variable in the textview!
        // - but it doesnt "remember" the value
        text.setText(someString);

    }
}
```

If I use static keyword on the someString variable, it remembers the value, but only the SECOND time i open the app!

I'm very new at this, and have tried google, and tried some stuff with a singleton class, but I just don't seem to understand this!

I would love it, if someone could link me some information to help me get this, AND give an example of how my code should be, so it will work!

THANKS! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is due to the fact that

```
text.setText(someString);
```

is executed immediately in the `onCreate` method, & by immediately I mean that **it does not wait for any response from the Volley request** (the Volley request that you set up before). In other words, you need to wait till you get a `response` before you set the text on to your `TextView`.

That's why it successfully sets your `TextView`'s text from within the `onResponse` method.

Comment: That definitely makes sense! Could you give me an example on how to wait till after the response to set the text?

Comment: You're doing it the right way : just set the textview's text from within the `onResponse` method. That's the only way to.

Comment: Oh okay. Problem is that the above code is an example of what Im doing.
I need to use the someString variable to some other stuff outside the onResponse method.
There is no way, to "wait for the respone" outside the onResponse method, and then do stuff?

Comment: All those stuff that you wanna do, must go inside the `onResponse` method then. (I don't know if there is a better way to do it, but it shall get the job done)

Comment: I found a solution now, based on the understanding from your information! THANKS!